# Specific permissions for rules components

Tags: 7, rules, users

I created two rules components but i can't find any module to set specific permissions for roles.

I want to let some role's users to allow run the first component but not the second one.
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Rules provides a UI to configure access to components based on a permission.

1. Edit the component
2. Click to expand "*Settings*"
3. Check "*Configure access for using this component with a permission*"

[image: Rules component permission setting]

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition to your component for *User has Roles*, change the data selector to *site:current-user:roles:* and set the roles you require for the component to run.